# How to test onClick props of a button using Jest and Enzyme

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I am trying to test a button which has an onClick function in React. My button looks like this:

```
<button 
          id='emailButton'
          className={classes.sceContactHeaderButton}
          data-toggle='collapse'
          data-target='#editEmailContact'
          onClick={props.handleToggle}
          tabIndex={0}
          title={(props.email.isOpen) ? 'Close Section' : 'Open Section'}
        >
          <span>{(props.email.isOpen) ? 'Close' : 'Details'}</span>
          <i className={(props.email.isOpen) ? 'fa fa-angle-up' : 'fa fa-angle-down'} />
        </button>
```

My test for the onClick() method is :

```
  it('check if the onClick method of the button exists', () => {
        wrapper.find('#emailButton').children().at(0).prop('onClick')();
    });
```

But I am getting an error saying:

`TypeError: wrapper.find(...).children(...).at(...).prop(...) is not a function`

What am I doing wrong? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `find('#emailButton').children().at(0).prop('onClick')` tries to call `onClick` prop on `<span>` rather `<button>`. you have mistargeted element

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think what you want is to simulate the event and not call it as a prop. Here is an example on how to do it:

```
 it('should call mock function when button is clicked', () => {
   const tree = shallow(
     <Button name='button test' handleClick={mockFn} />
   );
   tree.simulate('click');
   expect(mockFn).toHaveBeenCalled();
 });
```

I found this example in this article https://medium.com/backticks-tildes/testing-your-react-component-with-jest-and-enzyme-276eef45bea0

Comment: no, it's not correct. check https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/master/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/simulate.md : "Even though the name would imply this simulates an actual event, .simulate() will in fact target the component's prop based on the event you give it. For example, .simulate('click') will actually get the onClick prop and call it."

Answer (score 1):

**Successful to click props.button after too many trials**

MainButton.js

```
export default function MainButton(props) {
    let ButtonComponent = TouchableOpacity;

    if (Platform.Version >= 21) {
        ButtonComponent = TouchableNativeFeedback;
    }

    return (
        <View style={{...styles.buttonContainer, ...props.style}}>
            <ButtonComponent activeOpacity={0.6} onPress={props.onPress}> //Want to test props.onPress
                <View style={styles.button}>
                    <Text style={styles.buttonText}>{props.children}</Text>
                </View>
            </ButtonComponent>
        </View>
    );
}
```

MainButton.test.js

```
import { TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

describe('Main Button Component', () => {
    const goToMainScreen = jest.fn();
    const component = shallow(
        <MainButton onPress={goToMainScreen}>
            NEXT
        </MainButton>
    );

    it('should call onPress on click', async() => {
        const wrapper = component.find(TouchableOpacity);
        wrapper.getElement().props.onPress()
        expect(goToMainScreen).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```